# sd-card path list for any device

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I also face similar issue with being able to get sdcard path in android for the numerous android phones as discussed here by assif_tiger in 
[sd-card path list for all android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259403/sd-card-path-list-for-all-android-phone)

Answer (score 1):

There is no filesystem-level access for [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+, outside of a few locations (e.g., those returned via `getExternalFilesDirs()` on `Context`).

Answer (score 0):

First call [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()). If you get no response from that function, use `isDirectory()` and `exists()` on all the folder paths provided on [assif_tiger's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41259403/3259559).

Comment: This has nothing to do with an SD card on most Android devices.

Comment: @VeteranLK pls how do i get those folders since they seem to be phone manufacturer depended.Different phone brands and models have different path to sdcard and i think hardcoding sdcard path is not good practice.

Comment: @SBA, yes its a bad habit, but some devices returns null.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, some devices uses a part of it's internal memory as the external memory.

Updated docs https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#java